# Uninstalling EF Powertools from VS 15

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ef-power-tools

How can I uninstall EF Powertools from Visual Studio 15? I wanted to do this because I cant view entity framework menu when I right clicked. So I thought of installing EF Power tools again

Comment: Go to Tools, Extensions and Updates, locate and uninstall